# Python mocking can't get right return_value

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, return-value

I have the following function with image a python object from a module and having the method shape.

```
def foo(image):
    print image.shape
```

I want to mock the object image and it's return value

```
image = Mock()
image.shape.return_value = (0,0)
foo(image)
>>> <Mock name='mock.shape' id='4416382544'>
```

Calling foo(image), image.shape will return . How can I make it return (0,0)? (I need to get the value to test some condition like if image.shape = (0,0).
I'm struggling to have it work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `print` isn't `return`.

Comment: Also, shape isn't being accessed as a function -- It's a property.  You should be able to just do `image.shape = (0, 0)` where `image` is the `Mock` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
image.shape = (0, 0)
```

Set the attribute directly. `return_value` has nothing to do with attribute accesses.

Comment: Thanks. Even if i'm using def foo(image): return image.shape ? I'm not sure to see what return_value is for then

Comment: @RomanzoCriminale: `return_value` is for when you're calling something like a function. `image.shape.return_value` would be what you'd get if you tried `image.shape()` rather than `image.shape`.